# custom colors in filecurves stacked graphs Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, curve, stacked-area-chart

Now I am working on filecurves with 19 legends. The as default the graph have similar colors and not stacked correctly on the few bar on the right graph.

This is my data:

```
    a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s
201310  3   0   0   2   2   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   3   0   0   0   0
201401  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
201312  2   0   1   0   2   0   0   0   3   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
201305  3   1   0   4   9   0   2   4   1   4   1   1   2   0   2   0   0   0   0
201311  3   1   0   1   2   0   2   2   1   0   2   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   0
201306  5   0   1   2   4   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   3   0   0   1   0
201309  5   1   0   5   4   2   3   0   0   0   2   1   1   1   2   0   0   1   0
201308  3   1   0   2   6   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
201307  3   1   0   5   6   1   2   2   2   2   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
201303  6   0   0   1   1   2   1   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3   0
201304  5   1   0   0   4   2   3   3   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0
201302  3   0   2   2   2   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0
201211  11  0   3   0   1   0   4   0   0   0   0   4   0   1   0   0   1   0   0
201301  4   0   0   0   3   2   2   2   0   2   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
201212  5   1   0   4   0   4   5   2   0   2   0   2   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
201210  5   0   0   7   0   2   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
201209  3   1   1   7   1   1   2   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
201208  9   4   2   0   2   6   4   0   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1
201207  7   10  6   0   0   6   5   0   0   2   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0
201206  3   5   3   1   0   4   6   0   1   1   2   0   0   2   0   1   0   0   0
201205  5   6   4   2   1   5   2   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   0
201204  6   6   4   3   3   2   2   0   0   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
201203  14  12  10  4   0   2   1   2   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
201202  17  12  8   5   2   5   3   2   0   6   3   4   0   1   0   1   1   0   0
201201  14  7   11  4   4   0   2   5   1   5   7   1   0   0   0   2   0   0   1
201112  9   5   3   3   1   0   0   0   0   1   2   6   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
201111  13  4   3   5   2   2   0   6   0   1   2   3   0   3   0   1   0   0   1
201110  15  2   9   10  2   2   2   3   1   5   0   2   0   0   0   2   1   0   1
201109  17  15  16  5   3   3   5   3   2   2   2   4   0   0   0   1   1   0   1
201108  6   5   3   0   8   5   6   1   2   2   2   1   3   0   0   0   0   0   0
201107  10  4   9   0   4   5   8   8   12  3   7   3   2   0   0   0   0   0   0
201101  0   0   0   0   5   3   1   0   0   1   2   0   2   0   0   0   2   0   1
201102  0   0   0   0   1   3   0   0   0   0   3   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0
201106  1   1   0   1   3   5   4   1   1   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   1   0   0
201105  2   1   1   3   4   6   2   1   0   1   1   2   2   0   0   0   0   0   1
201104  1   1   0   1   1   3   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
201103  2   1   0   0   4   5   4   0   2   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0
```

and this is my gnuplot file:

```
set terminal postscript eps color font 20
#set key below autotitle columnheader
set key above autotitle columnheader
set xtics font "Times-Roman, 15" 
set ytics font "Times-Roman, 15" 
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y%m"
set format x "%b'%y"
set xrange ["201101":"201401"]
set grid

set output 'output.eps'
plot for [i=20:2:-1] \
"< awk 'NR==1 {print \"year\",$".(i-1)."} NR>=2 {for (i=2; i<=".i."; i++) \
{sum+= $i} {print $1, sum; sum=0} }' input.dat" \
using 1:2 with filledcurves x1 t column(2)
```

this is the output looks like:
[image: output]

I tried to delete 4 latest months and it look's better, but I need to put all date in my graphs. Please you comments.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data isn't monotonic in time. Usually you can use `smooth unique` but that doesn't work for me with filledcurves. But using `sort` after `awk` should do it. Try the following (cannot test it at the moment):

```
plot for [i=20:2:-1] "< awk ... input.dat | sort -r" using 1:2 with filledcurves x1 t column(2)
```

Comment: correct, to be honest I can't get the logic why I need sort here. but this is work for me... btw how about customs color of this?

Comment: Because your dates in the first column aren't sorted. So with your data set you first have Oct'13, Jan'14, Dec'13, May'13 etc. This gives some twists in the plot.

Comment: I set it now.  Thanks for explanations @Christoph.